# Addition of time difference of time zone (to GMT value)

Tags: php, time, timezone, gmt

The database stores values as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` *(eg 2013-04-14%2015:00:00)* which is in GMT time but the true value is the the above date and time + time zone difference of the server.

```
$time_heard = '2013-04-14%2015:00:00';
$time_diff = date('p')

$real_time = $time_heard + $time_diff  ;

echo $real_time ;
```

How can i do this addition.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL you can use the CONVERT_TZ functionality straight in the SELECT.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

If you need to do it in PHP, use the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) by [creating a new DateTime with the timezone set to GMT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) then [changing the timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) and when you [output the date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) it should display as the new timezone.

Comment: i'm using PostgreSQL, and i do not know the time zone (as they can vary, on where the installation is done). the other issue is that the $time_heard variable could also be a user input.

Comment: Then you're gonna have to use PHP. But the `$time_heard` can be used as user input when you're creating the DateTime object, just be sure to use an acceptable formatting. And to get the local server timezone, just use [date_default_timezone_get()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `date_default_timezone_set()` function to set the time to the zone you want

here you can find different zones: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

or if you insist, you can use date_parse_from_format()

here is the manual for it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php

edit: another way to do it with easy functions:

```
$tmstamp = strtotime($date1) + strtotime($date2);
echo date("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS", $tmstamp) ;
```

Comment: let me try the date parse, but how would i put it back together as it was before the addtion ( not as an array, but as a sting)

Comment: i added another easy way to do that, read it

Comment: '2013-04-14 15:00:00' <<- time heard
my time zone is Africa/Khartoum so 1hr difference

'1920-10-18 12:31:14' <<- what is this time

Comment: Keep in mind, in the second method, `$date1` and `$date2` can't have timezones in the string, otherwise `strtotime()` will convert it to GMT.

Comment: i understand,i am using numbers, ie '1 hr'